# How to fetch Array data in the key value format in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Can anyone please tell me how can we fetch the data from the below array which is in the form of key value.I want the information in the such a way:

```
select owner,TTL,class,Type, description;
```

Table :

```
[
    Owner: AWS00003Instance.domain.com.,
    TTL: 1200,
    Class: IN,
    Type: A,
    Data: 192.168.0.68,
    Description:default A rec, ,
    Owner: rr1.domain.com.,
    TTL: 1200,
    Class: IN,
    Type: A,
    Data: 192.168.0.68,
    Description:test
]
```

Thanks

Comment: You can't easily do this in MySQL, which has poor regex search/replace ability.  You should probably handle this outside of your database, before you bring the data into MySQL.

Comment: How to you connect to MySQL? `mysql` or with some programming language?

Answer (score 0):

With plain MySQL from command line, the best you can get without much efford:

```
select owner,TTL,class,Type, description\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
      owner: AWS00003Instance.domain.com.
        TTL: 1200
      class: IN
       Type: A
Description:default A rec
...
```